# How to convert date format using php?

Tags: php, date, datetime

How to convert date format using php ?

i tried to convert from `2015-02-24 03:21:56` to `Feb 24, 15 03:21:56`

i tried this code but not work, How can i do ?

```
<?PHP
    $date = "2015-02-24 03:21:56";
    echo $new_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $date);
?>
```

Comment: Read about `format` paramter in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to feed a text string into `date()`, when really it wants a Unix timestamp. So, you need to convert your input data to a Unix timestamp first, then feed that to `date()`.

Here is the code to do what you want:

```
<?php
    $date = "2015-02-24 03:21:56";
    $converted = strtotime($date);
    $new_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $converted);
    echo $new_date;
?>
```

Comment: how to show only `Feb` ?

Comment: If all you want is the word `Feb` (or `Jan`, `Dec`, etc), use `date('M', $converted)`.